Create mTLS Connection between NGINX and Tomcat
I have a Java application that requires a client certificate to authorize backend calls (note: this application is provided to us, and we cannot modify it).
When executing the command:
curl --cert bla.cert --key bla.key https://blablabla/context/foo

with the correct certificate and key, I receive proper authorization. If I use an incorrect certificate, authorization is denied.
Our Java application is put behind an Apache server followed by an NGINX reverse proxy:
The Apache reverse proxy validates the client certificate using a trust store and forwards the request to the NGINX reverse proxy without a client certificate.
NGINX then receives the validated request.
I need NGINX to send a specific client certificate when communicating with the Java application.
I have created a custom certificate and corresponding key, which the Java application accepts. Now, I need NGINX always to use this certificate as its client certificate when forwarding requests to the Java application.
How can i instruct nginx to send this client certificate?
location /foo/bar/ {

            proxy_pass https://server.domain.de:8443/foo/bar/;

            proxy_intercept_errors on;

        }

Thanks!

https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/securing-http-traffic-upstream/
